# How to query against dashing dashboard

Tags: rubygems

Is it possible to get the list of all dashboards defined in dashing. ie using curl or similar to query against specific endpoint.

I can send request to a specific dashboard, but my script is an external script that needs to consume the list of all existing dashboard and new ones as added.

It seem request works for using /dashboards/*, but at the moment there is only one event type "reload".

`curl -i -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "event": "reload"}' http://localhost:3030/dashboards/*`

Any work arounds will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/349.

Will implement one of the suggested answer,